# Very slow retrieval on android with 3G connection. Not with HSDPA or WiFi or on emulator

Tags: android, rest, tomcat7, 3g

This is a bit of a complicated question as I do not know the exact problem. The main issue is that it takes a very long to get a very small package of data from our REST server from our Android app. I will describe it in detail and hope you can help me.

**Problem**

Data retrieval is fast enough (+/- 100ms) when:

- Connected with WiFi
- Connected with HSDPA
- Running on Android Emulator with network settings (delay and speed) set to GPRS

However, when I use a phone on a location with bad connection (3G instead of HSDPA) calling the services can take up to 4s (current timeout on the AsyncTask).

**Android**

This is the code used to communicate with the services:

```java
 /**
 * Get json string from service
 *
 * @param urlString url of service
 * @return json result from service
 */
private String callService(String urlString) {
    InputStream in = null;
    HttpURLConnection c = null;
    Scanner s = null;
    String json = null;
    try {
        URL url = new URL(urlString);
        Log.i(getClass().getName() + ".callService()", "start calling service: " + url);
        long start = java.lang.System.currentTimeMillis();
        try {
            setAuthentication();
            c = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            c.connect();
            in = new BufferedInputStream(c.getInputStream());
            s = new Scanner(in);
            s.useDelimiter("\\A");
            json = s.next();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(getClass().getName() + ".callService()", "error: " + e.getMessage(), e);
        }
        Log.i(getClass().getName() + ".callService()", "complete calling service: (" + (System.currentTimeMillis() - start) + " ms) " + url);
        return json;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(getClass().getName() + ".callService()", "error: " + e.getMessage(), e);
    } finally {
        if (s != null) {
            s.close();
        }
        if (in != null) {
            try {
                in.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(getClass().getName() + ".callService()", "error: " + e.getMessage(), e);
            }
        }
        if (c != null) {
            c.disconnect();
        }
    }
    return json;
}
```

I have tried several ways to call this, but currently this is done using an AsyncTask:

```java
    /**
 * Retrieve json from service
 *
 * @param url url of service
 * @return json
 */
public String getJsonFromServiceBasic(String url) {
        ServiceTask task = new ServiceTask();
        try {
            return task.execute(url).get(4000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            Log.e(getClass().toString() + " getJsonFromServiceBasic(" + url + ")", " interrupt exception: " + e.getMessage(), e);
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            Log.e(getClass().toString() + " getJsonFromServiceBasic(" + url + ")", " execution exception: " + e.getMessage(), e);
        } catch (TimeoutException e) {
            task.cancel(true);
            Log.e(getClass().toString() + " getJsonFromServiceBasic(" + url + ")", " timeout exception: " + e.getMessage(), e);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(getClass().toString() + " getJsonFromServiceBasic(" + url + ")", " timeout exception: " + e.getMessage(), e);
        }
        return null;
}


/**
 * AsyncTask way of calling service
 */
class ServiceTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
        String json = callService(urls[0]);
        return json;
    }
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="16"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
```

**Services**

I do not think this is the issue, as it works fast enough with HSDPA, but I am not sure.
Restlet services on tomcat7 behind a proxy. We're using a ChallengeAuthenticator for authentication.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this problem by switching to Apache's HttpClient.
I am not sure why this is a solution as Google suggests using the HttpURLConnection, but for me this works.

Using this method instead of the callService method will solve my troubles with slow internet access.

```
private String callServiceClient(String urlString) {

    String json = null;

    HttpParams httpParams = new BasicHttpParams();
    int connection_Timeout = 5000;
    HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParams, connection_Timeout);
    HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParams, connection_Timeout);

    DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParams);
    httpClient.getCredentialsProvider().setCredentials(new AuthScope(null, -1),
            new UsernamePasswordCredentials(user, password));

    HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(urlString);

    // Execute the request
    HttpResponse response;
    try {
        response = httpClient.execute(httpget);
        // Examine the response status
        StatusLine responseCode = response.getStatusLine();
        Log.i(getClass() + ".callServiceClient()", "responsecode: " + responseCode);
        if (responseCode.getStatusCode() != HttpStatus.SC_OK) {
            return json;
        }

        // Get hold of the response entity
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        // If the response does not enclose an entity, there is no need
        // to worry about connection release

        if (entity != null) {

            // A Simple JSON Response Read
            InputStream instream = entity.getContent();
            json = convertStreamToString(instream);
            // now you have the string representation of the HTML request
            instream.close();
        }
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return json;
}
```